# Looping through lists, error : "float' object is not subscriptable".

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I want to create a new list of floats ES. The first value in ES = first value in L1. The rest of ES is based on the below formula: I need to do this without using any library/package.

Formula: es1 = (a * L1t) + (1 - a) * ES t-1

```
L1 = [430.92, 437.39, 535.03, 496.54, 520.72, 628.35, 679.06, 636.99, 574.81, 579.04, 598.50, 683.85]
a = 0.25
ES = []
ES.append(float(L1[0]))
for i in range(1, len(L1)):
    es1 = (a * (L1[i])) + ((1 - a) * ES[i-1])
    ES.append(float(es1[i]))
print(ES)
```

Comment: `es1` is a float, and you try to index it here: `es1[i]`

Comment: @TamasHegedus So how would you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message tells it all. If you look closely the interpreter even tells you the line in which the error occured. In this line (`ES.append(float(es1[i]))`) you try to subscript a value that is already assigned to a float in the previous line. Also you can get rid of the `float` constructors:

```
L1 = [430.92, 437.39, 535.03, 496.54, 520.72, 628.35, 679.06, 636.99, 574.81, 579.04, 598.50, 683.85]
a = 0.25
ES = []
ES.append(L1[0])
for i in range(1, len(L1)):
    es_i = (a * (L1[i])) + ((1 - a) * ES[i-1])
    ES.append(es_i)
print(ES)
```